# How do I make page.php search the file by name?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In Wordpress,
How do I make page.php search the post file by name. Ex:

```
<?php

while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
                  get_template_part ('dir/pages', $name);

endwhile;
?>
```

With the page slug with the same "$name"